# During partial wake up, handler.postdelayed() is sleep after few hours android

Tags: android, android-service

I do some data fetch work once in 10 seconds . Service to run background indefinitely and used asyntask to get data from server (JSON). The problem after few hours ,like 8 hrs handler goes to sleep .I again awaked the screen.The screen awaked up.but Thread is in sleep. So , I stop the service and again called service started but handler didn't run. I restarted the application , handler is working

Comment: sry for my bad english. *puring During

Comment: may i know your question

Comment: Problem is handler is in sleep .how to run handler not to go in sleep. While in partial wake lock.

Comment: did you add the wake lock permission in menifest file

Comment: yes.I did it. Give some example using alarm manager .If the alarm is called, asyntask needs to be called in service. Handler and thread are not working in deep sleep mode.